# using zend form decorators

Tags: zend-framework, forms, zend-form

```
<div class="field50Pct">
 <div class="fieldItemLabel">
  <label for='First Name'>First Name:</label>
 </div>
 <div class="fieldItemValue">
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

I want the code to appear like this in source code . how do i write the same thing in zend using decorators ?

The element is like

```
  $firstname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('FirstName');
        $firstname->setLabel('FirstName')
                 ->setRequired(true)
                 ->addFilter('StripTags')
                 ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                 ->addErrorMessage('Error in First Name')
                 ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for me:
(with `<div class="clear"></div>` after the input)

```
$firstname->setDecorators(array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Description',
        'Errors',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'fieldItemValue')),
        array(array('labelDivOpen' => 'HtmlTag'), 
              array('tag' => 'div', 
                    'placement' => 'prepend', 
                    'closeOnly' => true)),
        'Label',
        array(array('labelDivClose' => 'HtmlTag'), 
              array('tag' => 'div', 
                    'class' => 'fieldItemLabel', 
                    'placement' => 'prepend', 
                    'openOnly' => true)),
        array(array('fieldDiv' => 'HtmlTag'), 
              array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'field50Pct')),
        array(array('divClear' => 'HtmlTag') , 
              array('tag' => 'div' ,
                    'class' => 'clear',
                    'placement' => 'append'))
    ));
```

Comment: i ma new to zend ..can u just explain me the code you have written. so that i can try to write on my own next time!

Comment: how do i write 

<div class="clear"></div> after some elements??

Comment: Basically, I'm seting decorators to the firstname field.
http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450
http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/08/07/zend_form-decorator-tips/

Comment: how do i write <div class="clear"></div> after some elements??

Comment: i got ur code!1st one i am working on. what are the ones written 'ViewHelper','Description','Helpers' wht do they represent. and in the further code how does it recognise the class is for label / text box or whole field!!??

Comment: cant i add the class clear in the 1st example only bcos i have started to work on 1st example!

Comment: nope the earlier thing worked..but the clear thing did not work!

Comment: its coming like 
<div class="field50Pct"><div class="fieldItemLabel"><label for="LastName" class="required">LastName</label>

</div><div class="fieldItemValue">
<input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" value="" /></div><div class="clear"></div></div>

but the </div><div class="clear"></div> must come after last div ends i.e of the <div class="field50Pct"> ends

Comment: i placed the  array(
            array('divClear' => 'HtmlTag') , 
            array('tag' => 'div' ,
                  'class' => 'clear',
                  'placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::APPEND)
        ),
after the field50Pct class .so it worked thanks a lot ..

if u can help me with this question i will be greatful 

what are the ones written 'ViewHelper','Description','Helpers' wht do they represent. and in the further code how does it recognise the class is for label / text box or whole field!!??

Comment: ViewHelper represent the field itself, the description you can remove, since you're not using it (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.description). And about the HtmlTag that decorate the label, is due the parameters "openOnly" and "closeOnly", also due to the order that decorators are rendered. Please, take a look at the links I sent you.

Comment: for fieldset its coming in manner like 
<dt id="GeneralInformation-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="GeneralInformation-element"><fieldset id="fieldset-GeneralInformation"><legend>General Information</legend>
<dl>

i just need it in the ways like 
<fieldset id="personnel">
<legend>Personal Data</legend>
how do do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Do you want print just the fieldset without dt tag?